# Automatic Crash Dump for .Net process

Tags: crash, windbg, windows-error-reporting, postmortem-debugging, procdump

I'm trying to set up a Windows Server 2016 instance to automatically create a crash dump when a .Net process exits with an unhandled exception.  I've tried the following:

- Windows Error Reporting (as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/wer-settings) [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps\MyApplication.exe]
  "DumpType"=dword:00000002
  "DumpCount"=dword:00000005
  "DumpFolder"="C:\dumps"
- WinDbg as postmortem debugger (windbg -I, as descibed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/enabling-postmortem-debugging)
- procdump as postmortem debugger (procdump -ma -i C:\dumps, as described also in the above link.)

I've tried running my application in a way that will generate an exception.  All I have to do is start it twice in the same configuration, and the second instance crashes on a socket bind exception.  However, in none of the cases above does the crash generate a dump file.  Is there something special I have to do on Windows Server 2016, or something special I need to do to my .Net application to get it to trigger a dump on an unhandled exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason: we are using [TopShelf](https://github.com/Topshelf) to host our process. By default [TopShelf handles uncaught exceptions](https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf/blob/607ed2adbea8f27e57c8c6869f8890565ad13750/src/Topshelf/Hosts/ConsoleRunHost.cs#L157) and exits cleanly.

For any who come afterwards, please note that TopShelf has an undocumented feature from late last year to disable this behavior:

`x.UnhandledExceptionPolicy = Topshelf.Runtime.UnhandledExceptionPolicyCode.TakeNoAction;`

in the service configuration will do it.  With this code, I was able to get a crash dump.